# Python - Compare last name columns and get maximum similarity of them per row

Tags: python

I have a table with pairs of people. The aim is to compare the last names. However, some of them have a double-barreled last name which is already splitted into two columns. I want to do all the possible comparison among those last names and get the maximum similarity of them.

For example:
I have this table

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|person1_id |lastname1_1|lastname1_2 |person2_id |lastname2_1|lastname2_2 |
+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|1          |Johnson    |null        |6          |Johnson    |null        |
|2          |Smith      |Dorrien     |7          |Smith      |null        |
|3          |Scott      |null        |8          |Garcia     |Scott       |
|4          |Morris     |null        |9          |Flores     |null        |
|5          |Foster     |null        |10         |Nelson     |null        |
+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

The preferable result would be:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
|person1_id |lastname1_1|lastname1_2 |person2_id |lastname2_1|lastname2_2 |similarity|
+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
|1          |Johnson    |null        |6          |Johnson    |null        |1.0       |
|2          |Smith      |Dorrien     |7          |Smith      |null        |1.0       |
|3          |Scott      |null        |8          |Garcia     |Scott       |1.0       |
|4          |Morris     |null        |9          |Flores     |null        |0.5       |
|5          |Foster     |null        |10         |Nelson     |null        |0.16      |
+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

Is there any way to implement this?

Thank you.

Comment: What format is your table in? Is this a database or stored in a data frame? Also, how are you defining similarity? There are quite a few different ways of measuring similarity or distance between two strings.

Comment: Hi Andrew. It's a data frame. In this case, the similarity using SequenceMatcher would be fine I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. Firstly just recreating your data so you can see what I'm testing on.

```
import pandas as pd

person_one_first_surname_column = ["Johnson", "Smith", "Scott", "Morris", "Foster"]
person_two_first_surname_column = ["Johnson", "Smith", "Garcia", "Flores", "Nelson"]
person_one_second_surname_column = ["null", "Dorrien", "null", "null", "null"] 
person_two_second_surname_column = ["null", "null", "Scott", "null", "null"]



dataset = {'lastname1_1': person_one_first_surname_column, 'lastname1_2': person_one_second_surname_column, "lastname2_1" : person_two_first_surname_column, "lastname2_2": person_two_second_surname_column}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)
```

In the future, it would be helpful if you include your example data in code format to save people helping you time! I'm not sure how you're handling "null" values, so assumed they are a string too.

We start by defining a function which compares two lists of names. It works by making a new list of pairs `(a,b)` where `a` is from the first list, `b` is from the second, and only includes them if they are not equal to `"null"`. It then runs the Sequence matcher on them, and gets the ratio, before taking the maximum value from that list.

```
import difflib
def get_max_similarity(list_of_user_one_names, list_of_user_two_names):
    max_similarity = max([difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a,b).ratio() for a in list_of_user_one_names if a != "null" for b in list_of_user_two_names if b != "null"])
    return max_similarity
```

We now use the apply function to call our new function on each row of the data frame, feeding the list of names in as our variables. We assign this new data to the data frame as a new row, "Max_similarity".

```
df["Max_similarity"] = df.apply(lambda row: get_max_similarity([row["lastname1_1"], row["lastname1_2"]], [row["lastname2_1"], row["lastname2_2"]]), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  lastname1_1 lastname1_2 lastname2_1 lastname2_2  Max_similarity
0     Johnson        null     Johnson        null        1.000000
1       Smith     Dorrien       Smith        null        1.000000
2       Scott        null      Garcia       Scott        1.000000
3      Morris        null      Flores        null        0.500000
4      Foster        null      Nelson        null        0.166667
```

Comment: @VickyK Glad I could help.